# Error message displaying as "expression must have integral or enum type" in c++

Tags: c++

I have the following code and I am getting the error at  this equation:

```
v=p*(1+r)^n.
```

Please help me to find the reason for this error.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float v,p,r;
    int n;

    cout<<"Enter value of p:";
    cin>>p;
    cout<<"Enter value of r:";
    cin>>r;
    cout<<"Enter value of n:";
    cin>>n;

    v=(p)*(1+r)^n; // here i am getting error message as "expression must have integral or enum type"

    cout<<"V="<<v;

    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get(); 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**C++11 5.12 - Bitwise exclusive OR operator**

> exclusive-or-expression:
>       and-expression
>       exclusive-or-expression ˆ and-expression
>   1 The usual arithmetic conversions are performed; the result is the bitwise
>   exclusive OR function of the operands. The operator applies only to integral
>   or unscoped enumeration operands.

---

If you want to compute **v=(p)*(1+r)<sup>n</sup>**, you need to change

```
v=(p)*(1+r)^n;
```

to

```
v = p * powf(1+r, n); // powf: exponential math operator in C++
```

In `C++`, `^` is `XOR` (exclusive or) operator, e.g. `a = 2 ^ 3; // a will be 1`.

Check out [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) for more info.

Comment: Why? What's the cause of the problem and why does this fix it?

Comment: Thanks Herohuyongtao :)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `^` is not an exponential math operator in C++, instead it is a bitwise xor operation.  Bitwise operations can only be done on integral / enum values.

If you want to raise a floating point to a specific power use the `powf` function

```
powf(p * (1 + r), n)

// Or possibly the following depending on how you want the
// precedence to shake out
p * powf(1 + r, n)
```

Answer (score 0):

The bitwise exclusive OR operator ^

> applies only to integral or unscoped enumeration operands

(The C++ Standard)