# expression must have integral type

Tags: c, pointers

I get that compilation error because of this line which intended to increase the pointer by 0x200 (to point to the next segment)

```
Flash_ptr = Flash_ptr + (unsigned char *) 0x200;
```

I'v seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955318/error-message-displaying-as-expression-must-have-integral-or-enum-type-in-c) but I didn't use any illegal symbol!

P.S. The initialization of the pointer:

```
unsigned char * Flash_ptr = (unsigned char *) 0x20000;
```

Comment: The language doesn't allow you to add pointers (it doesn't make much sense). You can add an integral value instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't add two pointers. You can add an integer to a pointer, and you can subtract two pointers to get an integer difference, but adding two pointers makes no sense. To solve your problem therefore you just need to remove the cast:

```
Flash_ptr = Flash_ptr + 0x200;
```

This increments `Flash_ptr` by 0x200 *elements*, but since `Flash_ptr` is of type `unsigned char *` then this just translates to an increment of 0x200 *bytes*.

In order to make this part of a loop and check for an upper bound you would do something like this:

```
while (Flash_ptr < (unsigned char *)0x50000) // loop until Flash_ptr >= 0x50000
{
    // ... do something with Flash_ptr ...
    Flash_ptr += 0x200;
}
```

Comment: You are right the error has disappeared but how can I then check if the pointer points to address 0x50000 or less?
This just does not work:
 while(Flash_ptr < 0x50000)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to mention the invalid pointer *addition* used in OP's code.

Comment: @OgeeGee: You need to convert one of the operands explicitly, e.g. `while((uintptr_t)Flash_ptr < 0x50000)`.

Comment: @mafso `identifier "uintptr_t" is undefined`

Comment: @OgeeGee: It should be defined in `<stdint.h>` and was added in C99. In case you use C90, you can cast to another (sufficiently large) integer type, or you can do `while(Flash_ptr < (unsigned char *)0x50000)`. Note, that the latter is undefined if they don't point into the same (array) object.

Comment: Okie @mafso this leads to an infinite loop:

 `while(Flash_ptr < (unsigned char *)0x50000){
 Flash_ptr += 0x200;
 }`
any ideas?

Comment: @OgeeGee: No, not without further context. If the addresses involved are valid, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot **add** two pointers. What you can do is to **increment** the address held by the pointer. Remove the `(unsigned char *)`cast.

If you're interested, read more about pointer arithmatic [here](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html).